# IIS web page not loading

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm having a problem trying to load a web page in my mongoose installation. I get the following message when navigating to the URL. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

```
Server Error in '/WSWebClient' Application.
```

---

**Configuration Error 
Description:**

An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Source Error:**

```
Line 13:         <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 14:         <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 15:    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
Line 16:         <!-- Nevron (Diagram) Assemblies -->
Line 17:         <add assembly="Nevron.Diagram.WebForm, Version=9.3.24.12, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=95BCC3D41B0512E9"/> 

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WSWebClient\web.config    Line: 15 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0
LOG: DisplayName = System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/WSWebClient/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WSWebClient\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WSWebClient\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/wswebclient/c0740cfa/5af5eef5/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/wswebclient/c0740cfa/5af5eef5/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/WSWebClient/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/WSWebClient/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/wswebclient/c0740cfa/5af5eef5/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/wswebclient/c0740cfa/5af5eef5/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/WSWebClient/bin/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/WSWebClient/bin/System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Mvc.EXE.



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929 `
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states: Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why **the assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be loaded.** Normally, you deploy it to your website's bin. In this case, it didn't find it so it went and try to look for it in other paths, as it indicated in the log.

Check if you have a System.Web.Mvc.dll on your website bin folder. If you have it, and you still get the error, check that it is the correct version.

Comment: I checked the bin folder for the website but do not see the System.Web.Mvc.dll file in there. How can I get it? Sorry for the noob question... not to versed in IIS, .Net.

Comment: You should go back to the person who developed/deployed the site. It does not look like it has been deployed properly.